# TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jupyter_mode'

Tags: jupyter, plotly-dash

from the below doc, it says we can run app in notebook without using JupyterDash, instead we can just run app.run(jupyter_mode="external").

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-in-jupyter

However, I tried and I got an error of. I am running notbook in vs code. and version of dash is 2.7.0.  How to solve it? Thanks

```
import dash
print(dash.__version__)
2.7.0
```

```
TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jupyter_mode'
```

```
import time
from uuid import uuid4
import diskcache
from dash import Dash, html, DiskcacheManager, CeleryManager, Input, Output, callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

# from dash import jupyter_dash

# jupyter_dash.default_mode="external"

launch_uid = uuid4()
cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")


background_callback_manager = DiskcacheManager(
    cache, cache_by=[lambda: launch_uid], expire=60
)

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
           background_callback_manager=background_callback_manager)

# Simple layout with Start and Cancel buttons as well as a progress bar
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                dbc.Row(children=[
                    dbc.Col(),
                    dbc.Col(
                        children=[
                            html.P(id="paragraph_id", children=["Button not clicked"]),
                            # Progress component sets up the loading bar
                            dbc.Progress(id="progress-component", striped=True, value=5)
                        ]
                    ),
                    dbc.Col()
                ]
                ),
                dbc.Row(
                    children=[
                        dbc.Col(),
                        dbc.Col(
                            children=[
                                # Button kicks off the background callback
                                html.Button(id="button_id", children="Run Job!"),
                                # Button cancels the background callback
                                html.Button(id="cancel_button_id", children="Cancel Running Job!"),
                            ]
                        ),
                        dbc.Col(),
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
    ]
)


def calculate_percent_progress(iteration, total):
    percent = int((iteration / total) * 100)
    f_percent = f"{int(percent)} %"
    return percent, f_percent


def slow_process(set_progress):
    """
    This would be the slow function, need to set the progress on each iteration to update the progress
    bar.

    The 'set_progress' is a special argument with a function handle to update the app on current progress
    see: https://dash.plotly.com/background-callbacks

    :param set_progress:
    :return:
    """
    total = 10
    for i in range(total):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        percent, f_percent = calculate_percent_progress(iteration=i+1, total=total)
        set_progress([int(percent), f"{int(percent)} %"])


@callback(
    Output("paragraph_id", "children"),
    Input("button_id", "n_clicks"),
    running=[
        (Output("button_id", "disabled"), True, False),
        (Output("cancel_button_id", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("paragraph_id", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        )
    ],
    cancel=[Input("cancel_button_id", "n_clicks")],
    progress=[
        Output("progress-component", "value"),
        Output("progress-component", "label")
    ],
    interval=1000,
    background=True
)
def callback(set_progress, n_clicks):

    slow_process(set_progress)

    return [f"Clicked {n_clicks} times"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(jupyter_mode="external")
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_32408/3712129971.py in <module>
    109 
    110 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 111     app.run(jupyter_mode="external")
    112     # app.run(debug=True)

c:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\dash_tf\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py in run(self, host, port, proxy, debug, dev_tools_ui, dev_tools_props_check, dev_tools_serve_dev_bundles, dev_tools_hot_reload, dev_tools_hot_reload_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_watch_interval, dev_tools_hot_reload_max_retry, dev_tools_silence_routes_logging, dev_tools_prune_errors, **flask_run_options)
   1978                     extra_files.append(path)
   1979 
-> 1980         self.server.run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
   1981 
   1982     def _import_layouts_from_pages(self):

c:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\dash_tf\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py in run(self, host, port, debug, load_dotenv, **options)
    988 
    989         try:
--> 990             run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
    991         finally:
    992             # reset the first request information if the development server

TypeError: run_simple() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jupyter_mode'
```

Comment: Running in VSCode may be the issue? Where you link to shows actual Jupyter [there](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-in-jupyter) in the example images and the title is 'Dash in Jupyter Environments'. I imagine where you are running doesn't look like the images. And you aren't running it in a browser like the documentation says?

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I just ran the code in jupyter notebook and I got same error. so it is not related to vs code.

Comment: Hmmm...I was hoping it was that simple. Is your software running Jupyter older? Or brand new? I know the software running the server that allows it to use your browser recently changed dramatically to support the more JupyterLab-tech focused direction of development in Jupyter. And so it could just be a mismatch between what JupyterDash as the expected mode indicated and what your Jupyter currently indicates? Plus [the Jupyter-Dash](https://github.com/plotly/jupyter-dash#notice-as-of-dash-v211-jupyter-support-is-built-into-the-main-dash-package) readme indicates major shifts there. ...

Comment: I feel [this indicates here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/2629#issuecomment-1693354750) that your Dash is outdated because  `jupyter_mode` is definitely something it should be able to use. The current version is 2.13.0 which is much newer than you indicate using. Your version is almost a year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link (https://dash.plotly.com/dash-in-jupyter) says that jupyter support in dash started in 2.11. If you are using dash 2.7, you might need to update your dash.